# how to show alert in html page

Tags: javascript, html

how to show alert in html file while using four pages in single index.html
using paging.

I want that when page_two is clicked it show alert when that page is load

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#index"><img src="images/mockup4_22.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#page_one"><img src="images/mockup4_24.png"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#page_two"><img src="images/mockup4_26.png" id="check"/></a></li> 
    <li><a href="#page_three" ><img src="images/mockup4_28.png" id="btn" /></a></li>


    <li><a href="#page_four"><img src="images/mockup4_30.png"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: btw... why is the downvoting for?

Comment: yes why is the downvoting for this i am using 5 pages in single index.html file

Answer (score 2):

in the #page_two `onload` just put `alert("your message");`

```
<html>
  <body onload="alert(....);">
  .....
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He wants to show alert on click not on load.

Comment: @user1613360  `show alert when that page is load`

Comment: :Sorry man I forgot to read it fully.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="javascript:alert('your msg')";
```

i think like this.